# I'm trying to add BGM to my javaFx, but it keeps throwing exceptions

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using JavaFx 11 with OpenJDK 15.
I've watched many sample videos but still getting the errors.

Is that the problem of configuration?
My music file is in the same folder of src.
Can anyone help? Thanks!

This is my source code.

```
    import MonopolyRPG.Controller.GameModePage;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    
    import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    
    import javafx.scene.media.Media;
    
    
    public class Main extends Application {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            music();
            GameModePage gameModePage=  new GameModePage();
            gameModePage.start();
            primaryStage.close();
        }
    
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    
        public void music() {
            String filepath="file:///E:/MonopolyRPG-master/BGM.mp3";
            Media sound = new Media(filepath);
            //MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
            mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        }
    
    }
```

The errors keep occurs. And I tried to configure VM option and change .wav file to .mp3, still can't realise what happened.

Is this the correct syntax?

```
--module-path
C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib
--add-modules
javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\java.exe" --module-path C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=50311:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath E:\MonopolyRPG-master\out\production\MonopolyRPG;C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\src.zip;C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Users\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar MonopolyRPG.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager (in unnamed module @0x47300aa3) cannot access class com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.utils to unnamed module @0x47300aa3
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:110)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:107)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:90)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:239)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
    at MonopolyRPG.Main.music(Main.java:36)
    at MonopolyRPG.Main.start(Main.java:22)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application MonopolyRPG.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Post the complete stack trace as text, and format it as code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm asking question here for the first time.

Comment: Are you using gradle or maven at all?

Comment: @Matt no, i just create the project as JavaFx project

Comment: Try adding the option `--add-exports javafx.graphics` to the call to `java.exe`.

Comment: @James_D Thanks!! I've solved the problem by adding javafx.media